# Get a list of all keys in an Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, sorting

What I have: An array of hashes with different sizes.

```
hashes = [{:a => 0}, {:a => 0, :b => 1}, {:a => 1, :c => 1}]
```

What I need: I need a list of all keys. EDIT: An actual list, not a Hash.

```
[:a, :b, :c]
```

Is this the right approach? This feels a bit heavy.

```
hashes.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
```

Or any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what is merging strategy? take first value?

Comment: I don't believe you can improve on `hashes.flat_map(&:keys).uniq`. Note that the doc [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) states, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.", meaning that, for example, `[:b, a:, :c]` is not returned, should order be important. btw, I infer from your avatar that you are a conductor as well as a Rubiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is a good balance between performance and being idiomatic. I tried a few other approaches.

```
# with reduce
hashes.map(&:keys).reduce(:|)
# with merge
hashes.each_with_object({}) { |memo, h| memo.merge! h }.keys
# manually
set = {}
hashes.each { |h| h.each_key { |k| set[k] = nil } }
set.keys
```

the time in seconds for merging 1000 hashes with ~8 keys per hash 1000 times

```
uniq   0.539034
reduce 2.194463
merge  0.090131
manual 0.911875
```

For readability, your approach wins. Reducing sucks. Manual is ugly *and* slow.

I would go with the `merge` approach since it isn't very ugly and is super fast.

Comment: `Hash` is faster than `Set`. `each_key` is faster than `keys.each`

Comment: `set = {}; hashes.each {|h| h.each_key {|k| set[k]=nil} }; set.keys`

Comment: Or `hashes.each_with_object({}) {|a,b| b.merge! a}.keys`

Comment: Important point is that all these algorithms have the same linear complexity. So you can tune only the multiplication factor.

Comment: Updated based on comments. My manual benchmark was way off. Unsurprisingly the merge solution wins by a long shot: it's less dynamic and uses fewer method calls in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close

```
hashes.flat_map(&:to_a).reverse.to_h
#=> {:c=>1, :a=>0, :b=>1}
```

Comment: Is this more efficient?

Comment: than what? your code is efficient enough, but it doesn't return a data structure you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Ah sh**! Yes, what I need is a list of keys - not a hash. Sorry - will add an edit.